# How use regExp with spaces in map?

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-config

in site http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ i  get reg exp to detect mobile browsers by $user_agent

There is a code:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* "(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino") {
  set $index_file mobile.html;
}
```

how i can use this reg exp in map? like this:

```
map $http_user_agent $index_file {
  ~* "regexp" /mobile.html;
  default /desktop.html;
}
```

nginx get error `nginx: [emerg] invalid number of the map parameters in /etc/nginx/conf.d/prod.conf:2`

reg exp contains spaces. if i replace spages to `\s` then the regex stops working and no phones are detected.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Remove the space after `~*`
2. Remove double quotes around regExp
3. Replace spaces inside regExp with `\s`

```
map $http_user_agent $index_file {
  ~*(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\s|maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera\sm(ob|in)i|palm(\sos)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\s(ce|phone)|xda|xiino /mobile.html;
  default /desktop.html;
}
```